# Show that $\limsup \pi(n)/n = 0$ with elementary techniques.

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $S$ is a set $S \subseteq N$ and suppose 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|Z_n \cap S|}{n} = c \in (0,1).$$
How do we prove, using elementary means, that there is a composite number in $S$?

If this were not true, then we would have $\limsup \pi(n)/n > 0$, but that violates the prime number theorem. However, I want a direct and elementary proof. Can anyone give one?

Comment: equivalent to the harmonic sum of primes diverging, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes

Comment: @Willjagy, I am not convinced that is strictly the case. Don't you need to use an inclusion exclusion formula?

Comment: You over count the proportion of composite numbers.

Comment: Have you heard about Chebyshev's inequalities? They can be proved using elementary means.

Comment: @Jihad, I'm curious about what use you think those inequalities have here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes

In the long run, the proportion of numbers not divisible by $2$ is $1/2.$

The proportion of numbers not divisible by $2$ or $3$ is $(1/2)(2/3).$

The proportion of numbers not divisible by $2$ or $3$ or $5$ is $(1/2)(2/3)(4/5).$

Keep throwing in primes, the proportion of numbers not divisible by any of those in the list so far is the product of those $1 - (1/p).$

By taking enough primes, this product can be made as small as desired. The logarithm of the product is the sum of the logs. I get, for
$$  0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2},  $$ that
$$ -t - 2 t^2 \leq \log (1-t) \leq -t.  $$ As the harmonic sum of primes diverges, the sum of the logs goes to $-\infty.$